# How can I delete "read-only" excel files from a folder using R? { Preferably using the base functions like file.remove() }

Tags: r, file-manipulation

When i attempt to remove a "read only" file, the error message reads 'Permission denied'. However if I manually change the "read only" property, it works fine. Is there a way to, in general, remove "read only" files? If not, is it possible for me to change these properties using R directly?

Comment: What operating system is this for? How exactly are you changing the read-only flag?

Comment: windows 7,right click on the file -> properties -> manually change the attributes

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Windows, try using the `attrib` command to toggle the read-only setting. The following function will work:

```
rm.ReadOnly = function(filename) {
    system(paste('attrib -r ', filename, sep=''))
    file.remove(filename)
}
```